# How to "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" from QML file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have inherited a Qt project and I am trying to learn how to use Qt Creator. In the project, if I have a CPP file open, I can right-click on anything and select "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" and the IDE takes me to wherever the element is defined/declared.

The UI for the app is built with QML files, however, and there "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" has no effect. These QML files also contain references to custom class objects that are defined within the project, but I do not understand where these objects are declared or how the QML file "knows" what methods and properties these objects have (the IDE's intellisense shows these for the objects, although there is apparently no compile-time checking as I can change a valid property to an invalid one and the app will still compile and run).

Is there something else I need to do in order to make "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" work in a QML file?

Comment: I just discovered the same behavior 3 years later.